# How to output dataGrid Column to Labels?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid, label

I'm just trying to output a column of dataGridView control. The first code as shown below, it creates the labels and adds them into a list and form, everything is good. But the 2nd one, it doesn't work. How can I output to labels?

```
    public List<Label> labels;
    private void cmdBot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labels = new List<Label>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            Label gecoLabel = new Label();
            gecoLabel.Text = "test label";
            gecoLabel.AutoSize = true;
            gecoLabel.Location = new Point(100, 10 * i);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(gecoLabel);

            labels.Add(gecoLabel);
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (Label testLabel in labels)
            {
                testLabel.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["link"].FormattedValue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `[wpf]`? - that code is not WPF, it's winforms.

Comment: miss click, sorry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an extra loop in the second function that would cause each label to be set **FOR EACH ROW** from the DataGrid. But, since you didn't say exactly *how* it's not working, my only guess as to what you might be wanting is this (note that the second method is converted into being 1 extra line within the first method, but you don't *have* to do it this way if you don't want to):

```
private void cmdBot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labels = new List<Label>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        Label gecoLabel = new Label();
        //**Since you're already looping through every row, why not just set the label text at the same time?
        gecoLabel.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["link"].FormattedValue.ToString();
        gecoLabel.AutoSize = true;
        gecoLabel.Location = new Point(100, 10 * i);
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(gecoLabel);

        labels.Add(gecoLabel);
    }
```

EDIT: like @Dmitri E says, you also need to assign an ID for each label.

Comment: Yes, that code is working. Every different rows go to different labels. But while using my code, only the last row of the dataGrid goes to all labels. I need to use 2nd function to do that, thank you anyway

Comment: Did you give each label a unique ID? You could add a breakpoint or some debug MessageBox stuff that tells you how many labels you end up with in your collection and loops through them if necessary...

Comment: No I didn't and I don't want to do that because every label has events. and there is a lot of labels that they are using same event function by my way.

Comment: No way out of having to assign ID values, but if you were trying to avoid a bunch of extra debug pop-ups, why don't you just step through the method with the debugger? Or, you could have local variables (like an int for the label count and a List<string> for the text values) and then display those in your UI (for testing/debugging purposes only).

Answer (score 0):

```
Label gecoLabel = new Label();
gecoLabel.Text = "test label";
gecoLabel.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
```

Add that line to first loop. (each label MUST have an ID)
Then you can cycle through your labels find appropriate label and update it's text property

Comment: I already know that but I need to use my way if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your second code like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
            labels[i].Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["link"].FormattedValue.ToString();
}
```

You enter two loops and the last row of the grid value setting to the labels' text.